# Manifold of $SU(2)$ and it's relation to physical rotations

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, covering-spaces

I'm a physicist trying to make sense of some topics of group theory and their applications to quantum mechanics. Let me state the things I think I understand

**Special Orthogonal Group $SO(3)$**

This is the group of orthogonal rotations with unit determinant in 3-dimensions. We can parametrize them with a unit vector $\hat{n}$ and an angle $\theta=[-\pi,\pi]$ where $\hat{n}$ tells us the rotation axis and $\theta$ the rotation angle as long as we identify rotations with $\theta=\pi$ and $\theta=-\pi$. In other words, the group manifold is a 3-dimensional ball where antipodal points on the surface are identified.

Because we can parametrize the unit vector $\hat{n}$ with two other angles $\phi$ and $\psi$ that are coordinates on the 2-sphere $S_2$, the group manifold of $SO(3)$ is also parametrized by the three angles $(\phi,\psi,\theta)$ parametrizing a 3-sphere, as long as we only consider one hemisphere (since antipodal points are still identified).

**Special unitary group $SU(2)$**

This is the group of unitary matrices with unit determinant in 2-dimensions. We can parametrize its elements as

\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\-\beta^*&\alpha^*\end{bmatrix}

such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$. parametrizing this with $\alpha=a+ib$ and $\beta=c+id$ we get the manifold with $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 +d^2=1$ which is just a 3-sphere.

In physics, it's common to parametrize $SU(2)$ rotations in exponential form using Pauli matrices as

\begin{equation}
U(\vec{\theta})=e^{i\frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot \vec{\theta}}
\end{equation}

where $\vec{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ are the usual Pauli matrices and $\vec{\theta}=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ are three angles parametrizing how much we are rotating in each direction.

**Here's where I'm confused.** First, because this is supposed to be the effect of **physical rotations** on spinors, I'd think that the angles $\theta$ range in the usual way from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. However, it's easy to see that plugging $\theta=2\pi$ for any of the angles in $\vec{\theta}$ we get $U=-\mathbb{I}$, which can't be reached if we only let $\theta$ range from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. This makes me think that the manifold can be parametrized with angles ranging from $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$. However, this brings me to my second problem: I still have in the back of my mind that I will want to take the quotient group $SU(2)/Z_2$ and show that the manifold we get is the one for $SO(3)$. However, $SO(3)$  has radius $\pi$, not $2\pi$!

**In short, my question is: Given the exponential representation of elements of $SU(2)$ that I wrote above, what is the range of the coordinates $\vec{\theta}$?**

---

**My try at a solution**

I think that the elements in $SU(2)$ can be parametrized as

\begin{equation}
U=e^{i\frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\hat{n}\theta}
\end{equation}

where $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector and $\theta=[-2\pi,2\pi]$ measures the rotation. Here we identify elements $\theta+4\pi=\theta$. I'm already not convinced with this, since we know that the manifold of $SU(2)$ is a 3-sphere, which can be parametrized by one angle ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$ and another two angles ranging from $0$ to $\pi$. two of those can parametrize $\hat{n}$ and the last one can only go from $0$ to $\pi$, not to $2\pi$. Forgetting about this for a  moment, when we do the quotient group $SU(2)/Z_2$ we are identifying any elements on $SU(2)$ that differ by multiplication by an element of $Z_2=\{\mathbb{I},-\mathbb{I}\}$. That means that any two elements parametrized by the same $\hat{n}$ and angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ that differ in $2\pi$ should be identified as the same. We therefore get a manifold parametrized by a unit vector $\hat{n}$ and an angle $\theta=[-\pi,\pi]$ with elements differing in $2\pi$ idenfitied. Does this make sense?

My problem with this solution is also that if $SU(2)$ is parametrized in this way (that is, with a 3-dimensional ball of radius $2\pi$ and opposite points on its surface identified), then it wouldn't be simply connected!

Comment: TL;DR. $SU(2)$ is the unit $3$-sphere and can also be viewed as the set of unit quaternions. Now please read this standard [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). This will show that any two antipodal elements of $SU(2)$ give rise to *the same* spatial rotation in $SO(3)\,.$ This goes under the buzz word "double cover." Last not least: $SO(3)$ is $SU(2)/\mathbb Z_2$ but this is ***not*** a $3$-sphere. It is not simply connected. Topologically it is quite a monster.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your comment. I understand that SO(3) is not a 3-sphere. It is a half a hemisphere of a 3-sphere where the elements on the circumference of the hemisphere are antipodally identified. So I agree it's a monster. I see the sentence where I said that SO(3) was a 3-sphere, I was just refering to its radius, but I'll modify it. I also posted what I think answers all my questions

Comment: $SO(3)$ is the $3$-sphere $SU(2)$ with *any two* antipodal points identified. Even imagining $SO(3)$ as a hemisphere seems inaccurate to me. The radii of those spheres don't matter at all. I still read in your post that "$SO(3)$
 has radius $\pi$  not $2\pi$". That's nonsense.

Comment: In your words "SO(3) is the 3-sphere with any two antipodal points identified". If it is a 3-sphere with antipodal points identified, that 3-sphere should have some radius, no? I understand the manifold is not a 3-sphere, but a 3-sphere with antipodal points identified, but it still has some radius, I don't understand why you say it's nonsense. Your construction starts by saying it's a 3-sphere with some extra properties  on antipodal points of its surface but any 3-sphere needs a radius still. Anyways I think my answer solves both problems I posed. I was misunderstanding the SU(2) manifold.

Comment: $SU(2)$ being a good old three-sphere has a radius of one (neither of $\pi$ nor of $2\pi$). The upper hemisphere picture for $SO(3)$ with antipodes on the boundary identified I don't find as bad as I did first. If you want to speak of a radius of that hemisphere  my choice would be one as well. Are we perhaps mixing up a radius with an azimuthal angle?

Comment: ... correction: polar angle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out!

Indeed, any element $U\in SU(2)$ can be represented as

\begin{equation}
U=e^{i\frac{1}{2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot \hat{n}\theta}
\end{equation}

where $\hat{n}$ is a 3-dimensional unit vector and $\theta$ is an angle where we identify $\theta+4\pi=\theta$. Therefore the manifold can be thought of as a 3-dimensional ball of radius $2\pi$ where the surface is identified with the element $-\mathbb{I}$. This should be isomorphic to $S_3$.

**Concerns about $SU(2)$ not being simply connected**

My concern about this not being simply connected was funded by the usual construction one does for $SO(3)$ where one builds a curve that starts at the identity, goes all the way to the surface of the manifold, comes on the antipodal point and ties it back to the identity.  However, this is not a problem for $SU(2)$ because the manifold of $SU(2)$ doesn't have just an antipodal map, instead, every element at the surface $\theta=2\pi$ is the element $-\mathbb{I}$: We identify the whole surface as one element! So if we build a curve that starts at the identity, goes to the surface, comes on the antipodal point and goes back to the identity, we can easily deform it to a single point since every point in the surface is the same element.

**My concern about the quotient group**

The quotient group $SU(2)/ Z_2$ takes the manifold parametrized by a 3-dimensional unit vector $\hat{n}$ and an angle $\theta=[0,2\pi]$ and identifies any elements with the same $\hat{n}$ that differ by $2\pi$. That creates a manifold that is essentially two times the manifold of $SO(3)$! Which is the reason it's called a double cover! It starts at the identity, then builds a ball of radius $\pi$ with the antipodal points identified, and then it keeps going to radius $2\pi$ when it's the identity again! Since the manifold of $SO(3)$ can be thought of as a ball of radius $\pi$ with antipodal points on its surface identified, it's clear that the manifold of $SU(2)/Z_2$ is just twice this.